# Cross referencing a cell with sheet number

Tags: excel, vba

Have to start a complicated model of cross-referencing all cells in a Financial model.
I need to a code to start my model in which the code detects where a cell value is coming from and refer to the sheet number of that worksheet.

i.e. There are two worksheets, sheet 1 and sheet 2. Value in Range ("B3") of sheet1 comes from Range ("C4") of sheet 2. Likewise value in Range ("B4") of sheet1 comes from Range ("E7") of sheet 2.
I want the code to detect this reference, and in Range("B4") of sheet1 write i.e. Name of Sheet2.
Not looking for vlookup though.

Thanks

Comment: I think you want the result in column C not B as this would overwrite the original reference, or is that your intent?

Comment: There article does that: [VBA: Determine All Precedent Cells – A Nice Example Of Recursion](https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/vba-determine-all-precedent-cells-a-nice-example-of-recursion/).  It retrieves the cells` Precedents by triggering their `Range.NavigationArrows`  (which can be turned on manually from the formula tab)

Answer (score 0):

Naqi,

I think this will do what you want or at least give you a good starting point.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindSheetRefs()

   Dim rngStart As Range
   Dim lRowOfs  As Long
   Dim zRef     As String
   
   Set rngStart = Range("B3")
   lRowOfs = 0
   
   Do
      zRef = rngStart.Offset(lRowOfs, 0).Formula
      zRef = Left$(zRef, InStr(zRef, "!") - 1)
      zRef = Right$(zRef, Len(zRef) - 1)
      rngStart.Offset(lRowOfs, 1) = zRef
      lRowOfs = lRowOfs + 1
            
   Loop Until rngStart.Offset(lRowOfs, 0) = 0

End Sub 'FindSheetRefs
```

Sample output:

[image]

Note: The numbers in column B show where on the reference sheet the value resides, e.g. 34 = C4. I did this for quick referencing in testing.

HTH

P.S. I tried the code pointed to by TinMan on my sample and got this result in the VBA Immediate Window:

```
===
[Book11]Sheet1!$A$1 has no precedent cells.
===
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, appreciate your effort. The following code gives Error 5 "Invalid procedure call or argument"
           '[Ref = Left$(Ref, InStr(Ref, "!") - 1)]'
            '[Ref = Right$(Ref, Len(Ref) - 1)]'

Comment: Did you copy the code? It should be zRef vs Ref. Which line caused the problem for you? You have two lines referenced above.

Comment: Both lines,  zRef = Left$(zRef, InStr(zRef, "!") - 1)..........
      zRef = Right$(zRef, Len(zRef) - 1)